# How to get callback in instagram sharing

Tags: android, instagram

I am trying to sharing my data on Instagram but when I am shared my content on Instagram. I haven't gotten any success callback or when not shared then also not get failure callback. I am unable to found SDK for Instagram sharing as well as any API. Below I have mentioned my code by which I tried to sharing content on Instagram.

```
    // Create the new Intent using the 'Send' action.
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

// Limit this call to instagram
share.setPackage("com.instagram.android");

// Set the MIME type
share.setType(type);

// Create the URI from the media
File media = new File(mediaPath);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(media);

// Add the URI to the Intent.
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

try {
    // Fire the Intent.
    startActivityForResult(share, REQUEST_CODE);
} catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    // instagram not installed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Instagram docs](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/android-intents/). They didn't provide any callback to such sharing.

> If your application creates photos or videos and you would like your users to share them using Instagram, you can use Android Intents to open your media in Instagram's sharing flow.

Comment: Is there any way by which I can get the callback.

Comment: Unfortunately currently they are not with any SDK. So, the answer is NO.